# dlv fails to build __debug_bin under VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Consider debugging the following code:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {

    os.Args = append(os.Args, "help")
    
}
```

To test it with command line arguments I create launch.json as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Test args",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["-test.v","--","arg1","arg2","arg3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run *Test args* configuration from Run and Debug in VS Code I get an error message

> Failed to launch: could not launch process: open /mypath/__debug_bin:
> no such file or directory

This error is because for some reason dlv fails to create 'intermediate' binary file __debug_bin from under VS Code.

However, when I run dlv directly from command line

> dlv debug -- arg1 arg2 arg3

it works as expected, creates __debug_bin in /mypath directory and all further debugging features (setting breakpoints, stepping over/into, printing variables etc) are available.

Moreover, if I first run dlv debug from command line (creating thus __debug_bin) and then (without quitting dlv) switch to VS Code and run *Test args* from Run and Debug, it works too. Meaning that VS Code (and dlv somewhere under the hood) catches this __debug_bin and uses it for debugging.

So, the trouble is that dlv fails to build __debug_bin when called from VS Code context.

Please advise how can I fix this issue?

EDIT.
The trouble happened because of using wrong "mode" and "args" parameters in my launch.json file.
Proper debug configuration looks as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["--","arg1","arg2","arg3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed "mode" from "test" to "auto", and removed "-test.v" flag from "args".
Configuration with "mode": "test" and "-test.v" in "args" works for testing scenarios. Say, when I have main_test.go and main.go, and I want to debug main_test.go.
If I debug a 'normal' (not 'test') go file, I need to adjust launch.json as described.